# Can I listen to a Bluetooth data receipt on a broadcast receiver on android and if I can, how?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth

I'm trying to build a Bluetooth emergency beacon(a MCU hooked up to a Bluetooth module),which after I press a button sends some data to my android app on my phone. I want to listen to this data reception (even when the app is not in the foreground) and then do something in my app, like call 911. So what's the way to do that, if there's any.

Comment: As it has been done [several times before](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/dont-panic-just-use-your-bluetooth-emergency-button/), yes you can!

Comment: @Risto just waiting for the part that explains how.

Comment: when I look at your question from above, it says "Can I listen to a Bluetooth data receipt on a broadcast receiver on android?" and my answer is "yes you can!" ;-) If you would like to have a different answer, then you should formulate exactly what you want. You could e.g. show us your source code with which you have problems, then your question would also be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this page. So I am left with just a typical Have you read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner)?

Comment: @Risto OK fair. But I also asked "...with a broadcast receiver", are you supposed to know that the example you linked me to  actually does it with a broadcast receiver. Fair enough then. We'll be here all day if we nitpick about the logistics of language. Also in the elaboration part of the question, I've made it explicit that I want a way to do that if there's any. So I too am left with just a typical Please also read the explanation to the question, there's a reason it's there for.

Comment: Sorry if I sound hostile. I'm not too good in English. I edited my question. Thanks!